# How does a computer control electric circuits?

Tags: computers

I would like to know how it is posible for a computer command to phisically start something like a motor or spotlight when they are on such a different scale. How can such a small signal have such a huge effect?

Comment: A basic circuit called an "amplifier" does exactly that. Makes a small signal, able to move mountains!

Comment: Computers are bigger on the inside.

Comment: The same way an audio signal of a few milliwatts can be amplified up to many kilowatts in a car audio system for example

Answer (score 4):

The computer produces a 'logic level' signal of a few volts at very low current.

That can be amplified and used to operate a mechanical relay or a solid state relay to as high power as is required.

For example, the milliwatt range logic level output could drive a small [transistor](http://media.digikey.com/Renders/Micro%20Commercial%20Renders/353;TO92-Formed;;3_sml.jpg), and the transistor could drive a ~1W coil controlling a [30A relay](http://media.digikey.com/photos/Tyco%20Potter%20Brumfield%20Photos/T90N1D12.jpg) for an appliance. The power to operate the relay would generally be supplied externally. The relay could switch 240VAC at 30A, which is over 7kW.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about switches...computer sends a signal to "flip a switch" on a circuit and make something do something, like a motor turning on. The computer doesnt power the motor, rather tells another circuit what to do (I.E. faster, slower)

Now, its actually much more complicated but that sums it up.